# compiling HTML in parent Scope -Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

m trying to compile HTML in parent Scope

i have created a custom directive that has isolated scope. i have used **Mustache** rather to use ng-repeat to create HTML that looks like

```
app.directive('createDiv', [  '$window','$compile',
function ( $window, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {   
        },           
        link: function (scope, element) {                                  

                var tpl = '<div>' +

                '<div id="main">{{#divs}}' +
                   ' <div id="{{id}}" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options="{accept: \'.draggable\'}" jqyoui-droppable="{onDrop:\'dragDrop.dropCallback\'}" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropCallback($data,$event)">' +

                    '<div id="{{id}}_fields" ng-include="main.tpl"></div>' +
                    '</div> {{/divs}}' +
                '</div>';
                Mustache.parse(tpl);
                html = Mustache.render(tpl, data);

                $compile(html)(scope);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    element.html(html);
                }, 100);
            });        

        }
    }
}]);
```

and the parent controller

```
app.controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function ( $scope) {
    var main={}
    main.tpl='scripts/templates/main.html'; //this gets changed based on condition
    $scope.main=main;
    }]);
```

M using it like this

```
<div ng-controller='MainController'> <div create-div></div></div>
```

i dont know why its not working . i get HTML and its inserted in div but its not reflecting main.HTML , in DOM it look like this

```
<div id='main'>
<div id="{{id}}" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options="{accept: '.draggable'}" jqyoui-droppable="{onDrop:'dragDrop.dropCallback'}" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropCallback($data,$event)">>
<div id="{{id}}_fields" ng-include="main.tpl"></div>
</div> 
</div>
```

how can i make ng-include work and also if any change occurs it should reflect that. Any help will be appreciated

**Edit**

i have solved it using

```
app.directive('createDiv', [  '$window','$compile',
function ( $window, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",                
        link: function (scope, element) {                                  

                var tpl = '<div>' +

                '<div id="main">{{#divs}}' +
                   ' <div id="{{id}}" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options="{accept: \'.draggable\'}" jqyoui-droppable="{onDrop:\'dragDrop.dropCallback\'}" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropCallback($data,$event)">' +

                    '<div id="{{id}}_fields" ng-include="main.tpl"></div>' +
                    '</div> {{/divs}}' +
                '</div>';
                Mustache.parse(tpl);
                html = Mustache.render(tpl, data);


                setTimeout(function () {
   $compile(html )(scope, function cloneAttachFn(prelinkedClone) {
                          element.html(prelinkedClone);
                        });                    

                }, 100);
            });        

        }
    }
}]);
```

but now issue is that if html gets too big like 2000 div elements its take a lot of time and it hangs browser

Regards